# How to install waydroid in deepin v20?

Tags: deepin

I want to install some android apps in my deepin Linux system.

On the Internet, it is said that waydroid can install Android
applications in Linux.

So how to install waydroid in deepin?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to install some android apps in this system

Well, Android is quite different from a desktop Linux distribution. I'll go as far as saying that the main thing that both have in common is the kernel – anything userspace is quite different. So you need quite a few layers of abstraction in between.

It's not really "installing android apps in my system", it's really more "setting up a somewhat complete emulated Android and installing things in there".

> So how to install waydroid in deepin?

From Wikipedia's [Deepin page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepin):

> Deepin […] is a Linux distribution based on the Debian "stable" branch.

And Waydroid's installation page has a section on [*Ubuntu, Debian and Derivates*](https://docs.waydro.id/usage/install-on-desktops#ubuntu-debian-and-derivatives). Since your distro is derived from debian, you need to follow the steps there.

Comment: great, another site using brawndo-installer.  and that installer script is like nails on a blackboard to me.  I wish app devs cared enough about security to just tell people "download this gpg key, install it in this directory, then add XXX to your sources.list" rather than encourage people to be reckless with stuff like "download this URL and pipe it straight into sudo bash".  that can completely trash or compromise a system if the devs are malicious. or just incompetent.  brawndo does not inspire trust.

Comment: @cas yeah I was looking for anything that just you know explicitly lists dependencies. I was about to write something based on the debian/ directory in that repo. But then I thought, no. This might just change within the blink of an eye, and then the information here would be misleading. In the end, the debian packaging seems to be not *that* different from the upstream fedora packaging, so there's at least one reviewed method that an expert could later work with. But it's, honestly, a mess.

Comment: unfortunately, it's fairly typical.  extremely common yet still extremely annoying.  a shame, waydroid looks interesting and useful.  too bad it's not packaged IN debian.

Comment: @cas I mean, considering that fedora in its .spec explicitly rips out the downloading of images, my guess is that for debian packaging, you basically would need to argue for downloading nonfree software in a free package, which might be a no-go (don't know about debian's policies wrt that)

Comment: In Debian, free software that installs/downloads/depends on non-free sw goes into the `contrib` section.  e.g. `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` - the installer program is free, but it downloads & installs microsoft's proprietary fonts. Same for various free sw clones of Doom and Quake and other games that rely on non-free game data. And emulators like vice, uae, xtrs, zsnes, yuzu, etc.